# Create a view to list contents according to taxonomy & content type

Tags: 7, views

I have vocabulary with these terms

- Countries

  - India
  - USA
  - UK
  - ...
- Sports

  - Soccer
  - Hockey
  - Cricket
  - ....

And I have following content types

- News
- Events
- Article
- ...

I need to create view that will show listing of content(s) as per the following path

for example:

/sports/soccer/news

/countries/india/news

or

/news/sports/soccer

/news/countries/india

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can create views pages with next pathes:

"taxonomy/term/%/news"

"taxonomy/term/%/events"

"taxonomy/term/%/articles"

Install [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and add "[term:parent]/[term:name]" pattern for URL alias for your vocabulary, and install [Sub-pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module that will apply aliases for URL like this 'taxonomy/term/1/news'